# How to show hide rows in table using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have this table:

```
<table style="cursor: pointer; width: 100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="4">
                                <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/pushpinred.png" runat="server" Width="32"
                                    Height="32" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td rowspan="7">
                                <input type="button" id="btnToggleRow" value="B" style="height: 30px; position: relative; float: left;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="textDesc">
                            <td>text:</td>
                            <td rowspan="4">
                                <h1 style="color: gray"><%# Eval("Text") %></h1>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="hidden">
                            <td>text:</td>
                            <td><%# Eval("Text") %></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="hidden">
                            <td>X:</td>
                            <td><%# Eval("Lon") %></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="hidden">
                            <td>Y:</td>
                            <td><%# Eval("Lat") %></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                    </table>
```

and here is jQuery that I try to use:

```
        $('.toggleRow').on('click', function () {



            return false;
        });
```

Here how it looks in view:

[image]

As you can see it is table,each row has 3 elements image text and button. Also I have rows in table that are hidden.

When button **B** clicked I need the jQuery function above fired.

Inside function I need to get all hidden rows and make them visible and make invisible row that has `textDesc`  class.

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

you have the jquery functions `.show(); , .hide(); , .toggle();` which does exctly what you think.

attach them to the element you want to show / hide.

for example:

```
 $('.toggleRow').click(function(){
     $('.toggleRow').toggle();
 });
```

Comment: But first I need to access the hidden element  how can I do it?

Comment: do you mean an acutal hidden element (display:hidden) or the elements with the class "hidden"

Comment: an acutal hidden element

Comment: what the .hide(); or .show(); does is change the css attribute of Display. so to accsess that element just use it's id/class with $('someid').show(); and the attach to it the function that you need